# Passing luks passphrase to unlock encrypted rootfs with script instead of passing from the terminal

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption

I would like to develop a script which passes LUKS passphrase instead of passing from the keyboard when cryptroot asks user to unlock. I tried to modify cryptroot script, but not able to run it.

It would be great if I get any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The [previously answer by @Quanten](https://superuser.com/a/1179108/167207) is wrong.

This should be enough

```
echo "123" | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 sda1 -
```

A key-file is different from a password.

Comment: Thanks for posting! So [is the comment from the original poster on the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1179108/167207) correct when they say “I had tried this, but not able to get it.”

Comment: I don’t believe it’s necessary or appropriate to claim another answer is incorrect.  If another answer is incorrect, you should downvote and comment saying it’s incorrect, but if you know the answer submitting a correct answer is absolutely warranted.  Consider removing that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Cryptsetup has an option `-d` or `--keyfile` and with a dash as filename, cryptsetup reads from the stdin [(see manpage)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup)

With this, you could pass the password from an environment variable to cryptsetup:

```
echo $password | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXX cryptroot -d -
```

The exact syntax depends on your script.

If this would be a good idea, in a security perspective is another question...

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this, but not able to get it. And I would like to replace askpass executable with passphrase string in the cryptroot. Could you please help me with this, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It worked for me after I added `-n` to `echo` to prevent adding a newline to the password: `echo -n $password | cryptsetup open ...`

Comment: Minor correction: it's `--key-file` in the manual. I don't know if it changed or it's new, but that's what it was on nixos 23.11,

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do in Python

```
    import os
    import time
      
    system_password = "admin"
    pass = "password123"
    key_file = "/root/key_file"
    slot = 1
    os.system("echo %s > %s" % (system_password, key_file))
    cmd = "echo -n %s | /sbin/cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdx --key-file %s --batch-mode --key-slot %s" % (pass, key_file, slot)
    os.system(cmd)
```

To remove the passphrase

```
cmd = "echo -n %s | /sbin/cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sdx" % (pass)
os.system(cmd)
```

Make sure echo command has `-n` option, just to make sure newline is not included in the password.